# IntelliJ sourcing .sh in external tools is not working

Tags: java, bash, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When i run my spring boot web service, i want to source myscriptfile.sh which contains lots of export commands in order to modify my web service URLs based on the environment of the current shell, before building my project.

I can run it in terminal using this command:

```
source /path/to/my/script/file/myscriptfile.sh; mvn spring-boot:run
```

But sometimes i want to do debugging on my project in IntelliJ, so i try to configure it to run that script before build process in external tools.

The configuration looks like this:

[image: run configuration]

but when i try to debug my project i get

```
bin/bash: source: No such file or directory.
```

I not sure what is wrong with the setting, can anyone help?

Comment: Are you just sourcing environment files to simulate a local profile as an example? I'm just curious why you need the script to source the environment?

Comment: It might be that your working directory points to your script instead to parent folder of your script.

Comment: @JacobBlanton I did this because i can source different environment for my project to connect to...such as databases url, based on the exports i defined in the script.

Comment: @dmadic I made sure it points to that folder that contains the script file, is it not configured that way?

Comment: @CrazyCoder when i run it from the terminal , it works. It looks like this:
`source /path/to/my/script/file/myscriptfile.sh; mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: This won’t do what you want, by the way. IntelliJ will just run your “External Tool” command and exit. Your Maven command will then be executed in a completely different environment without any of your settings from the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

use `/bin/bash`, except for any other things like `env xxx`

Answer (score 0):

As @Strelok has mentioned in the comment, the maven command executes in a completely different environment. You should set the environment variables manually at `Run/Debug Configurations --> Environment variables`.